# MySQL Slow Query Lock_time = years?

Tags: mysql, locking, mysql-slow-query-log

I have seen a lot of slow query logs, but never one like this:

```
    /usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.1.46-log (SUSE MySQL RPM). started with:
    Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
    Time                 Id Command    Argument
    # Time: 160627  9:10:05
    # User@Host: sysop[sysop] @  [127.0.0.1]
    # Query_time: 3.768728  Lock_time: 0.034402 Rows_sent: 734  Rows_examined: 734
    use asterisk;
    SET timestamp=1467033005;
    select PostID, lead_id, list_id from vdlist_temp where Posted is null;
    # Time: 160627 10:35:11
    # User@Host: sysop[sysop] @  [192.168.0.248]
    # Query_time: 35.563521  Lock_time: 0.000054 Rows_sent: 1222017  Rows_examined: 2444034
    SET timestamp=1467038111;
    SELECT `vicidial_list`.`lead_id`, `vicidial_list`.`source_id` FROM  `vicidial_list` ORDER BY `vicidial_list`.`source_id`;
    # User@Host: sysop[sysop] @  [127.0.0.1]
    # Query_time: 0.000095  Lock_time: 18446744073699.406250 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 1
    SET timestamp=1467038111;
    call spUpdate_VDList_from_temp(0, 0, 1324903);
    # Time: 160627 10:35:12
    # User@Host: sysop[sysop] @  [127.0.0.1]
    # Query_time: 0.000055  Lock_time: 18446744073699.359375 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
    SET timestamp=1467038112;
    call spMoveXDrop(10376163);
    # Time: 160627 11:26:14
    # User@Host: sysop[sysop] @  [127.0.0.1]
    # Query_time: 0.000057  Lock_time: 18446744073697.218750 Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 0
    SET timestamp=1467041174;
    call spUpdate_VDList_from_temp(10795520, 616062301, 1955758);
```

This seems to show I have queries waiting over 500,000 years for a lock. (I wrote the stored procedure and I'm not quite that old!) Somehow I don't think that's right.  These are all MyISAM tables. (Not my choice.)  I did a mysqldump and restore of the database, rebooted the server and I'm still getting seeing lock times like this.

Can anyone give me a clue where to look for the problem?  (Server times are all good.)

EDIT:This MySql Version: 5.1.46-log that comes with an OpenSource project Vicidial.  It seems clear that the Lock_time is a bug.  Problem is that I'm looking at the slow query log to track down user complaints of slow web server response.  I was hoping someone would know what triggers this bug to help me locate the actual problem.  As you can see from the log, most slow queries have sane Lock_times. Both stored procedures and PHP generated queries generate the insane Lock_time.  The only thing I see in common is they all select or update from the table vicidial_list.  I dumped, dropped and recreated that table to no avail.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Despite being a great question, it might be better to create a bug report for this at mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the clock seems to run backwards.  This has been a problem for more than a decade.  It seems to be harmless.  Ignore it as a bogus value.

Note that if a `-1` is stored in a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, you get a value very similar to the `18446744073699.406250` that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Those queries are not part of stock VICIdial, so I might suggest some query optimization for those custom queries you're trying to run. Also, in more recent versions of our VICIbox ISO installer we are using MariaDB, and a much newer version as well, which has a lot of bug fixes and optimizations compared to the older version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: We're running Server version: 5.1.46-log SUSE MySQL RPM.  Are the MariaDB tables still ISAM?  Also, it seems there is not much optimization to a query like `code` SELECT `vicidial_list`.`lead_id`, `vicidial_list`.`source_id` FROM  `vicidial_list` ORDER BY `vicidial_list`.`source_id`;`code`

Comment: Sorry about the screwed up mini-Markdown.  I'm not allowed to edit my own comments!

Comment: Yes, MariaDB still uses MyISAM tables, it is a drop-in replacement for MySQL.